# What does 普段からmean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrases

> 中山さんは普段からよく運動するようにしています。

I think it means

> Mr. Nakayama tries to do exercise regularly

But I'm confused about what 普段からactually means and how it differs from 普段and 普通

Answer (score 5):

> 「中山{なかやま}さんは普段{ふだん}からよく運動{うんどう}するようにしています。」

「普段から」 means "routinely" here.  You have made a habit of doing something on a regular basis.

We also use 「日頃{ひごろ}から」 and 「常{つね}日頃から」 for virtually the same meaning.

We never say 「普通{ふつう}から」 to mean "doing something on a regular basis".  You can, however, say something like:

> 「中山さんは普通（は）毎日１時間運動しますが、今日は３０分しかしませんでした。」

"Nakayama-san usually works out for an hour everyday, but s/he only did 30 minutes today."

In other words, you can (loosely) replace 「普段から」 by 「普通（は）」 in many contexts but never by 「普通から」.

「普通（は）」 means "usually", but compared to 「普段から」, it somehow lacks the strong nuance of "routine" or "habit".

Comment: Thank you! If I replace `普段から` with `普段`, would the above sentence still mean the same thing? `中山さんは普段よく運動するようにしています。`